# Is the constructor or the code the problem?

Tags: c++

I am new to learning C++. I tried to create a code that is meant to tell time and add minutes to it by using a constructor. However, upon building the code with CodeBlocks, an error is displayed under the scope resolution 'time::time()'.

I tried creating parameters within the constructor but to no avail.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class time
{
private:
    int hours,minutes;
public:
    time(int);
    ~time();
    void enterTime();
    void addMinutes();
    void displayTime();
};
time::time()
{
    int timehours;
    int timeminutes;
    cout<<"Enter hours: "<<endl;
    cin>>timehours;
    if(timehours<00 && timehours>23)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Entry of time. Try again."<<endl;
        time();
    }
    else
        timehours==00;
    cout<<"Enter minutes: "<<endl;
    cin>>timeminutes;
    if(timeminutes<0 && timeminutes>59)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Entry of time. Try again."<<endl;
        time();
    }
    else
        timeminutes==00;
    cout<<"Initial Time: "<<timehours<<": "<<timeminutes<<endl;
}
void time::enterTime()
{
    cout<<"Enter hours: "<<endl;
    cin>>hours;
    if(hours<00 && hours>23)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid entry of time. Try Again."<<endl;
        enterTime();
    }
    cout<<"Enter minutes: "<<endl;
    cin>>minutes;
    if(minutes<00)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid entry of time. Try Again,"<<endl;
        enterTime();
    }
    cout<<"Initial Time:- "<<hours<<": "<<minutes<<endl;
}
void time::addMinutes()
{
    if(minutes>60 && minutes%60>0)
    {
        int addhours,addMin;
        addMin=(minutes%60>0);
        addhours=(minutes/60);
        hours+=addhours;
        if(hours>=24)
            hours-=24;
    }
}
void time::displayTime()
{
    cout<<"Updated time:"<<hours<<" :"<<minutes<<" "<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    for(n=0;n<4;n++)
    {
        time Time[4];
        if((n+1)%2==0)
        {
            Time[n].time();
            Time[n].addMinutes();
            Time[n].displayTime();
        }
        else
        {
            Time[n].enterTime();
            Time[n].addMinutes();
            Time[n].displayTime();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? You don't have a constructor that takes in 0 arguments though ...

Comment: Tangential, but look carefully at the logic for validating the `hours` entry.

Comment: Use `time::time(int a)` , then fix other errors.

Comment: The constructor does take argument.

Comment: Always post complete error, always.

Comment: You've just discovered why you will do yourself a huge, huge favor if you complete forget that `using namespace std;` is part of C++, and promise to never use it again, or at least until one reaches expert-level C++ knowledge, and understands the full implications of doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *two problems* with your code as described below:

---

##### Problem 1

The first problem is that you're trying to define the default constructor outside the class while you have **not declared it inside the class**. Remember that in order to define any member function outside the class, its corresponding declaration must be there inside the class first.

So to **solve** this remove the `~` which actually made that declaration a destructor declaration, as shown below:

```
class time
{
private:
    int hours,minutes;
public:
    time(int);
//-v---------------------->removed ~ from here
    time();

    //other code as before
};
```

---

##### Problem 2

Additionally avoid using `using namespace std;` so that there is no conflict between names of user defined classes and standard library names. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

You have a conflict between the class time, and the [function time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) from the standard library.

Here

```
time Time[4];
```

the compiler expects a parameter for the function call.

This is one reason for avoiding `using namespace std`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the reported error mentioned by op. Though OP will eventually need to resolve it as well.